# Websocket handshakes failing on PHP

Tags: php, iis, websocket, chat, messaging

I'm trying to setup a websocket server in a development pc. I've been trying a few examples from github and all of them with the same result. Error 500 after a few minutes.
I already have enabled the websocket protocol on Windows optional resources, the extension is included in the php.ini file. I tried running the scripts on CMD and nothing seems to work. I also tried inserting a few breakpoints using xdebug and the script is being reached, it just keep refusing to perform the handshake. Is there anything that I may be missing?

The PC is running Windows 10, with PHP 5.6.3.

Comment: Did you deploy the application on IIS? What's the result if you test it on develop tool not IIS? Error 500 is a general error, there's no useful error information in this code. If you want to get detailed error information, you can use failed request tracing to check.

Comment: It's deployed on IIS, I try to run the PHP script via CMD, and then load the html file that will make the request, and it keeps in the "CONNECTING" state for a few minutes until it returns a handshake error. I already checked the PHP logs and it's empty. I think it can be a configuration problem because I've already tried so many example codes and all of them had the same result... I just have no idea of what it may be.

Comment: What's the log of failed request tracing? Did you check that log and what it record about 500 error?